# I have a map<string, vector<record>>, how to remove records from vector<record>?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, segmentation-fault

I have tried all possibilities I could, and failed to find solution. Please help

I want to remove records in vector in map while iterating over it.

```
map < string, vector < record> >::iterator map_it;
for(map_it = map_records.begin(); map_it != map_records.end(); ++map_it){
    vector < record>::iterator vec_it;
    for(vec_it = (*map_it).second.begin(); vec_it != (*map_it).second.end();){
        if(condition){
            cout << (*map_it).second.size() << endl;
            vec_it = map_it->second.erase(vec_it);
            cout << (*map_it).second.size()<< endl;
        } else {
            ++vec_it;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this,
`(*map_it).second.erase(vec_it)`
It give some long number if I query the size of it and program ends with segmentation fault

OUTPUT:
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
Segmentation fault

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   vec_t = map_it->second.erase(vec_it); //note the assignment!
```

You also need to check it's validity immediately, so better re-write the inner loop as:

```
for(vec_it = (*map_it).second.begin(); vec_it != (*map_it).second.end(); )
{
    if(condition)
        vec_it = map_it->second.erase(vec_it);
    else
      ++vec_it;
}
```

Comment: @Ringo: If you're getting some error. Then the problem is somewhere else, not in this loop anymore. Why don't you post the error message as well?

Comment: @Ringo: Are you doing `++vec_it` in the `for` also? Did you notice I don't do that? My code increments it ONLY AT ONE PLACE!

Comment: Error is 
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
Segmentation fault
I am just incrementing in case if condition failes.

Comment: @Ringo: Are you increment twice? Post the `for` loop also, which you're currently working with!

Comment: @Ringo: See you're not assigning the return value from `erase` :             `map_it->second.erase(vec_it);`.. where is the return value? did you read my FIRST LINE in my post Carefully? Did you read the comment where I said `note the assignment!`?

Comment: I am sorry, I did that in my code for got to update here. I am not doing a copy paste of code here. Rewriting.

Comment: @Ringo: If you're not copy pasting, and then you're typing something else, then what is point of writing the code in the first place here which is not same?

Comment: Ok, I will copy paste as you said.

Comment: @Ringo: One thing is sure. The bug is not in the loop. So it would be better you post more code, as to how you initialize the map, and vectors and all.

Comment: @Ringo: You accepted the answer. It seems it solved your problem. May I know what was the bug?

Comment: Actually my code is some 100 lines, if you want I will send the code offline (if you have time), I have initialised all the variable/.

Comment: I could not solve bug yet, that was a mistake of clicking vote up.

Comment: @Ringo: Send at `nawazzz@gmail.com` . ... note : there is 3 `z` in the email id!

Comment: It is a bug in my code. Method to erase vector items is correct. Thanks for help. Special thanks to nawaz..

Comment: @Ringo: Congrats that you fixed the problem yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**You are invalidating your iterator.** If you are going to erase objects from your vector while iterating over it, you should be sure to take the return value of erase (which is the iterator of the next object, or vector::end) and set the iterator to that, otherwise it will become invalid and your program will probably crash.

```
if(condition){
        vec_it = map_it->second.erase(vec_it);
    }

    //added for completeness
    //if the for loop has a ++vec_it, we should break before
    //it gets to do it on an end iterator
    if(vec_it == map_it->second.end()) {
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using conditional erases on a vector, rather use the `std::remove_if`. and then `erase` idiom. It will be quicker because it will not move all elements of your vector multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

In the conditional, you can do this:

```
vec_it = (*map_it).second.erase( vec_it );
```

And it'll erase the item in the map at that iterator position.

[More Info on C++ Vector::Erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

Comment: That is not map's erase that you're calling!

Comment: A hahahaha. hahahahahah. Oops. >.>